# Better Version for Backtracking

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

Given n tasks, each can be performed in 1 unit of time and tasks can be performed in parallel. Each task can only be done within a given time bound, say between time t1 and t2 (both inclusive)(t1 <= t2). Aim is to find maximum tasks that can be performed at 2 time instants.
Example: for 5 tasks (n=5),

Task 1: {1, 5}

Task 2: {3, 4}

Task 3: {5, 6}

Task 4: {7, 12}

Task 5: {8, 100}

Here we can perform maximum of 4 tasks.
Tasks 1 and 2 can be performed at time instants between [3, 4] and tasks 4 and 5 can be performed at time instants between [8, 12].

OR

Tasks 1 and 3 can be performed at time instant 5 and tasks 4 and 5 can be performed at time instants between [8, 12].
Now here's C++ version of backtracking algorithm:

```
int result = 0, n;
int task[1000][2];

//Checks if task overlaps with the time range [t1, t2]
bool taskFit(int &taskno, int &t1, int &t2){
    if(task[taskno][1] &lt t1)return false;
    else if(task[taskno][0] > t2)return false;
    else return true;
}

void backtrack(int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4, int taskno, int grp1, int grp2){
    //t1, t2 represultent time bounds for group1
    //t3, t4 represultent time bounds for group2
    //grp1: number of tasks that can be performed in time range of group1
    //grp2: number of tasks that can be performed in second time stamp

    result = max(grp1 + grp2, result);
    if(result==n || taskno==(n+1))return;

    //putting task in first group if it fits in the range of group1
    if(taskFit(taskno, t1, t2))
        backtrack(max(t1, task[taskno][0]), min(t2, task[taskno][1]), t3, t4, taskno+1, grp1+1, grp2);

    //putting task in second group if it fits in its range
    if(taskFit(taskno, t3, t4))
        backtrack(t1, t2, max(t3, task[taskno][0]), min(t4, task[taskno][1]), taskno+1, grp1, grp2+1);

    //simply ignoring the task
    backtrack(t1, t2, t3, t4, taskno+1, grp1, grp2);
}

main(){
    //...we have the value of n and time range of all n tasks
    // for ith task time range in obtained as [task[i][0], task[i][1]]

    //initially both groups are set in time range = [0, 2000000000]

    //here we put the task1 in first group
    //thus setting the new range for group 1
    backtrack(task[0][0], task[0][1], 0, 2000000000, 2, 1, 0);

    //ignoring the first task, the group ranges remain as it is
    backtrack(0, 2000000000, 0, 2000000000, 2, 0, 0);
}
```

The above backtracking algorithm considers 3 cases for a task, it lies in group1 or group2 or doesn't belong to any group.

Initially the group ranges are large enough so that all tasks can be put in them, but as we add a task to a group the time range converges.

I know that this algorithm works correctly, but for some inputs, its complexity turns out to be exponential.

Thus is it possible to optimize this algorithm or may be i should go with some another strategy? Please let me know the optimizations or concept if other strategies are applied.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain an algorithm that (I think) should have a N<sup>3</sup> time complexity, and N<sup>2</sup> memory complexity (N being the number of tasks). I will try to describe where it comes from & how it works first, but you can jump to the end if you just want the pseudo code.

## Step 1: Reindex your input data

First, I would like to represent your input data in a matrix (or "doodle") way. If I take a subset from your example:

```
+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|        | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+
| Task 1 | X | X | X | X | X |   |   |   |   |    |    |    |
| Task 2 |   |   | X | X |   |   |   |   |   |    |    |    |
| Task 3 |   |   |   |   | X | X |   |   |   |    |    |    |
| Task 4 |   |   |   |   |   |   | X | X | X | X  | X  | X  |
+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+
```

Currently, your data are indexed by row: `task[taskIndex] // --> time interval of this task`. What happens if we reindex by column: `availableTasks[timeIndex] // --> set of tasks that can be executed at this time`?

With a naive implementation of this data structure, we could write the following naive algorithm (in pseudo C++):

```
int MAX_TIME = 2000000000; // 2,000,000,000
// reindexed input
std::unordered_set<int>; availableTasks[MAX_TIME];
// main algorithm
int bestTotal = -1; // result
int r1, r2; // time values to get bestTotal
// brute force: try all pair of time values:
for (int t1 = 0; t1 <= MAX_TIME-1; t1++) {
    for (int t2 = t1; t2 <= MAX_TIME; t2++) {
        int count = union(availableTasks[t1], availableTasks[t2]).size();
        if (count > bestCount) {
            r1 = t1; r2 = t2;
            bestCount = count;
        }
    }
}
```

Good news: the time complexity is not exponential anymore ! Bad news:

1. Huge memory usage: due to the value of `MAX_TIME`, `availableTasks` will be several GB even with few tasks.
2. Ridiculous execution time: the double loop have approximately 2*10<sup>18</sup> iterations. On a 4Ghz CPU at 1 iteration/cycle (extremely optimistic), it's more than a decade.

So any practical solution cannot brute force through all pairs of time values.

## Step 2: restrict time value candidates.

Let's take a simple case with 2 tasks:

- Task 0: [1;1 499 999]
- Task 1: [500 000; 1 999 999]

Intuitively, you would say that it isn't necessary to test the 2,000,000 time values. You would consider that there a 4 intervals of time values (upper bound excluded):

- Interval A: [1; 500 000[
- Interval B: [500 000; 1 500 000[
- Interval C: [1 500 000; 2 000 000[
- Interval D: [2 000 000; MAX_TIME[

If  `Ta` and `Tb` are selected in the same interval, we have  `availableTasks[Ta] == availableTasks[Tb]`. So basically, we just have to test a single time value in each interval. I will choose the lower bound to represent each interval: 1 | 500,000 | 1,500,000 | 2,000,000.

*<sub>Note: In math terms, we are [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) the set of time values, by defining an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) : `t1~t2 <=> availableTasks[t1] == availableTasks[t2]`, then selecting a representative element from every equivalence class.</sub>*

Where do these representative values come from ? Easy:

```
tasks[0][0] // 1
tasks[1][0] // 500,000
tasks[0][1] + 1 // 1,500,000
tasks[1][1] + 1 // 2,000,000
```

**First candidate restriction rule:** We are sure to find an optimal solution if we test all pairs in the set `S={tasks[*][0], tasks[*][1]+1}`.

This should already restrict enough values to make the algorithm work in a reasonable time, but we can do simpler and faster. The values in the previous set can be interpreted as follow:

1. `t=tasks[k][0]`: task k can't be executed in previous interval (ending at `t-1`), but can be executed in the interval starting at `t`
2. `t=tasks[k][1]`: task k can be executed in the previous interval (ending at `t-1`), but can't be executed in the interval at `t`

From this point of view, the interval starting at `t` in case 2 is a useless candidate: unless there is a `l` verifying `tasks[l][0] == tasks[k][1]+1` (meaning: at time t, there is another task that becomes executable, so t also falls in case 1), any time value in the previous interval is necessary a better candidate (because `availableTasks[t-1]` strictly contains `availableTasks[t]`). Therefore:

**Better candidate restriction rule:** We are sure to find an optimal solution if we test all pairs in the set `S={tasks[*][0]}`.

## Algorithm (untested, pseudo C++)

Generating reindexed input data:

```
int n = 1000; //number of tasks
// availableTasks[timeIndex] : set of tasks executable at timeIndex.
// Only candidate values are stored in the map.
std::map<int, std::unordered_set<int>> availableTasks;
for ( timeCandidate : task[*][0] ) {
    auto& set = availableTasks[timeCandidate];
    for ( int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < n; taskIndex++) {
        if (timeCandidate in task[taskIndex]) {
            set.insert(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Main algorithm:

```
int bestTotal = -1; // result
int r1, r2; // time values to get bestTotal
auto& map = availableTasks; // alias
for (auto it1=map.begin(); it1 != map.end(): it1++) {
    int t1 = it1->first;
    auto& set1 = it1->second;
    auto it2 = it1; // copy the iterator
    it2++;
    for (; it2 != map.end(); it2++) {
        int t2 = it2->first;
        auto& set2 = it2->second;
        // assuming here that union().size() can be computed in O(n) time.
        int count = union(set1, set2).size();
        if (count > bestCount) {
            r1 = t1; r2 = t2;
            bestCount = count;
        }
    }
}
```

If this algorithm works, I think it might be possible to refine it further in terms of spatial & time complexity. But this post is already quite long ^^. First I suggest that you check that this one is correct and if it meets your performance requirements.